# Unable to connect to Phantom 4 Pro v2 with SDK

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Today we bought Phantom 4 Pro v2. When trying connect to this drone, but SDK returns unknown model name.

How can we get to work it with v2? Other drones (Mavic Pro, Phantom 4 Pro) working well with this SDK.

Used Android SDK 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the MobileSDK 4.5.1 (Android or iOS) doesn't support Phantom 4 Pro v2.

It's plan to come with Mobile SDK 4.6 which should come in a few weeks.